Python doesn't recognize mysql library after installing it correctly
I have installed mysql apparently well, this is what I wrote in the terminal:
pip install mysql

and this was the result:
Collecting mysql
  Using cached mysql-0.0.3-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (746 bytes)
Requirement already satisfied: mysqlclient in c:\python312\lib\site-packages (from mysql) (2.2.4)
Using cached mysql-0.0.3-py3-none-any.whl (1.2 kB)
Installing collected packages: mysql
Successfully installed mysql-0.0.3

but after that, when I import the library i have the error: Import "mysql" could not be resolved. I don't know how to fix it. I had a lot of problems with vscode.

Sounds like you have two different installations of python on your computer.  Please show us the output of this in vscode import sys; print(sys.path)

do this outside of VSCODE and see what happens, post ALL code and error messages   - do not paraphrase with the likes of 'it didn't work', 'it gave error', just copy/paste the code and messages (NO SCREENSHOTS either)

Hello, do you have multiple interpreters? It may be because the location of the download and the interpreter chosen are inconsistent. You can do this by using the Ctrl+Shift+P to enter the panel, type select interpreter to select the interpreter.

According to PyPi:

This package is a ‘virtual package’, which requires MySQL-python (Python 2) or mysqlclient (Python 3) to install. In effect, this means ‘pip install mysql’ will actually install MySQL-python. Instead of depending on this package, please depend on the relevant package directly.

Since you're using Python 3.12, what you need is mysqlclient. To install, run
pip install mysqlclient

